# Constrain an argument to an inner type of a template class

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I'd like to have a concept, which restricts the type to a nested class of a template (e.g. a `std::vector<...>::iterator`). I can't change the template and its nested class.

```
template<class T>
struct A
{
  struct B {};
};

template<class T>
concept is_B = requires(T x) { []<class U>(typename A<U>::B){}(x); };

void foo(is_B auto) {};

void bar()
{
  foo(A<int>::B{});  // should compile
  foo(int{});        // should not compile
}
```

The code above doesn't work, since `U` cannot be deduced (which resembles a little bit the notorious question about template argument deduction for nested classes).

Is there a way to write such a concept?

Comment: Not possible, and I don't see a good reason to do it anyway (for `std::vector`). Are you looking for [`std::contiguous_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/contiguous_iterator)?

Comment: Why would you need a `is_vector_iterator` concept when you can just pass your `std::vector<T>::iterator` directly as argument ? Actually, a `has_iterator` concept would make more sense, IMHO.

Comment: The question is not about `std::vector<...>::iterator`, it only served as a well known example. Actually it is about `std::experimental::simd<T, U>::reference`.

Comment: No matter what it is in reality, I used `vector` just to illustrate the idea. In your case, why don' you just pass a `std::experimental::simd<T, U>::reference` in your function since it's what is expected ? Using a concept in that case does not make much sense to me.

Comment: Concepts are meant to apply constraints requirements for template types. Which is not what you want. Since you want a function which accepts a single, already known type, you don't need templates at all, just specify the target type in parameter. You will never find a concept _"is_<type_of_your_choice>"_ for the same reason, it does not make sense. If you ever needed a "is_double" (or a "is_B"), then you just need to pass a `double` (or a `B`) directly, a template that accepts only one defined type has no reason to be a template.

Comment: There is no 1:1 relation between `A<T>::B` and `T`, if you want one you need to establish it yourself. If you like you can write a trait that enables you to write `get_T_from_B<B>::type`.

Comment: @Farenor: the above is a minimal example. There is also an overload to `foo`, which takes a simple reference to any type. `std::experimental::simd<T, U>::reference` acts weird wrt. to assignments: if you want to assign values to it, you have to convert it to an rvalue.
I have now solved it by restricting the other overload to copyable types. This works in my specific case, but it is not a solution to the general problem (for which there seems to be none).

Answer (score 0):

You could brute-force it with a type trait that is specialized to be true for a specific set of types, and false otherwise. Then you could create a concept from this trait

```
template<class> struct is_legal : std::false_type {};
template<> struct is_legal<typename std::vector<int>::iterator> : std::true_type {};
// more of previous line
template<class T> concept my_concept = (is_legal<T>::value);
```

This is could be shortened with a macro:

```
#define IS_TRUE(t) template<> struct is_legal<t> : std::true_type {};
IS_TRUE(typename std::vector<int>::const_iterator)
```